# Does there exist a surjective function from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can I say that cardinality of $(0,1)$ is less than the cardinality $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: There exists a **bijective** function from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: In the title, do you mean *injective* function? It takes an injection $A \hookrightarrow B$ to say that the cardinality of $A$ is *at most* the cardinality of $B$.

Answer (score 5):

$ x \mapsto \min( \max( 2x - \frac{1}{2}, 0 ), 1 )$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = \sin^2 (2\pi x)$ will do the job.